# Sts <mvc:annotation-drive/> error

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I don't know why this error is happening.

```
[Error occurred processing XML 'org/springframework/format/support/FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean'. See Error Log for more details]
```

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2iHG.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post your code directly inside the question instead of an image

Comment: Thank u very much!! :)